# Builds section not showing in Visual Studio 2013 for GIT projects

Tags: git, build, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I have a project open in Visual Studio 2013 that is hosted in Visual Studio Team Services.

I have builds running in Team Services but for some reason I am missing the Builds section in Visual Studio's Team Explorer. It's a Git project, in case it makes a difference.

I do see the Builds when I connect to a TFS server that uses Team Foundation Version Control.

Any ideas why I can't see the Builds section in Visual Studio?

Comment: Am experiencing this issue with VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Getting VS team explorer to pick up a git project that you created without doing it the "expected" way can be tricky. I found using the refresh option in the Connect page of team explorer, along with closing and re opening VS often can make it recognise that the got redo is hosted on TFS in VS Team Services.

Once it understands the got two matches one hosted in TFS the build page will appear.

Comment: I had already tried those options, but it didn't work. I ended up cloning the project again and voila, the Builds are now visible.

Comment: It does seem a little silly - I've struggled with it in the past, I'm not sure how it's supported to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up cloning the project again and the Builds section showed up in Team Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Visual Studio **Professional** and I have been told that I need visual Studio **Enterprise**.